# Homeomorphism from $\mathbb{N}$ to $T = \{1/n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm trying to understand what is probably a basic topological fact and I'm probably overthinking it.  I'm consider the map $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow T$ where $T = \{1/n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ defined by $f(n) = 1/n$, where $\mathbb{N}$ and $T$ have the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ and I'm trying to show that this is a homeomorphism.  Clearly, the map is a bijection.  My issue is trying to show that the map is bicontinuous.  I was thinking about the usual definition of continuity, that a map is continuous if the inverse image of open sets are open, so I let $U$ be some open set in $T$.  Then $f^{-1}(U) = A \subset \mathbb{N}$, and I was thinking that I could show that $A$ is open under the subspace topology.  Any element of $\mathbb{N}$ can be viewed as $(n-\frac{1}{2}, n+\frac{1}{2}) \cap \mathbb{N}$, and since $(n-\frac{1}{2}, n+\frac{1}{2})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, then $\{n\}$ is open in $\mathbb{N}$ with the subspace topology.  Since singletons are open, I can just view $A$ as the union of a bunch of singletons, which is an arbitrary union, and hence open.  Hence $f$ is continuous.  And then I can do something similar to show $f^{-1}$ is continuous.  Is this the right idea or am I just trying to hard and missing something simple?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s the right idea, and it’s a lot simpler than you seem to be making it. Just show that each of the spaces has the discrete topology, so that **every** subset of $\Bbb N$ and **every** subset of $T$ is open. Then continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ becomes trivial.